# Scheduled task in django

Tags: python, django, cron, cron-task

I need explanation for scheduled task

I need to run task in every end of the day automatically like cron

I tried **schedule** app in my project

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    pprint.pprint("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

when i add above code in project  site was loading continuously

Question: Need to create task run automatically in background without user knowledge and without any command? It is possible?

I am new for python and django

Please suggest any idea for this task

Comment: on what capacity do you use django here? the example doesn't make any reference to it.. if you are, then try https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab - it's great for managing cron jobs in Django

Comment: @Martin how to check crontab in localhost

Comment: depends on your OS, try googling it first

Answer (score 4):

If it is not an overkill - I recommend [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).
It has "Celerybeat" which is like "cron"

Actually I think this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Do agree with you Celery looks like the right thing to implement for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you create a management command (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it from a cron job.